# Take input stream while recording

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, inputstream, mediarecorder

Is it possible to take the input stream (that creates the ouput video file) from the media Recorder in any way?
I have a method that takes 2 parameters (both input streams for video files). I want to append the second one to the first. I have made this, but it is a little slow. I would want to send data to append to my first video, while recording (or directly the input stream, if not somekind of buffer that fills and then sends). Is this possible?
I have looked in the source code of android.media.MediaRecorder, but the start function is only a call to `public void native start()`. The stop method is just the same and i cannot imagine where the video is created. Is it done natively? can i aquire the stream?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having a similar problem, any help will go a long way thanks

Comment: nope, just used isoviewer as a library, and took more videos and then concatenate them at the end